# Conemu startup with a task opening multiple tabs

Tags: conemu

Is there a way with conEmu to by default open a number of different tabs?
I saw this page explaining how to do this with [splits](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#example-7),
and I realize I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I was hoping there was a way to do this automatically!

```
"%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -cur_console:t:"repo1":C:"%GIT_HOME%\git-bash.exe":d:"%USERPROFILE%\code\repo1"

"%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -new_console:t:"repo2":C:"%GIT_HOME%\git-bash.exe":d:"%USERPROFILE%\code\repo2"

"%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -new_console:t:"repo3":C:"%GIT_HOME%\git-bash.exe":d:"%USERPROFILE%\code\repo3"
```

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html

Comment: If I set this task that does this as the default task, it won't open up all 3 of the tabs like I want it to, it only opens the tab for `repo1`.

That is unless I manually do the hotkeys to get it to choose `open all task tabs`, rather than that being done automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by "default task"? How (when) do you want to open these the tabs? What version do you use?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is possible but not via the settings Dialog of Conemu. You need a small config file

1. Create Config File

   1. Go to Conemu installation directory (like *C:\Program Files\ConEmu*)
   2. Create file *startup.txt*
   3. List the consoles you want to open at startup. For example

   > >C:\Program Files\staab\Git\bin\bash.exe
   >
   > >C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

   will open Git Bash and cmd at startup (in that order). If you want to set the startup directories for each console you can do this too:

   > >C:\Program Files\staab\Git\bin\bash.exe -new_console:d:C:\example\path
   >
   > >C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe -new_console:d:C:\other\path
2. Start Conemu with that config file

   1. Create a new desktop shortcut for the *ConEmu64.exe* (or *ConEmu.exe* if you use the 32-Bit version)
   2. *Right click > Properties* on that shortcut.
   3. Add **/cmd @startup.txt** to the target

   [image]
3. Now you can link that shortcut to your task bar or put it in the autostart folder of your computer to start Conemu with those consoles right after login.

### Update 1: Name for Tab

I just found out that you can also set the name of all the tabs on startup :-)

> >C:\Program Files\staab\Git\bin\bash.exe -new_console:d:C:\example\path **-cur_console:t:NAME_OF_TAB**

### Update 2: Admin Rights

And this is how you give admin rights to the tabs of your choice:

> >C:\Program Files\staab\Git\bin\bash.exe -new_console:d:C:\example\path **-new_console:a**

Don't use this more than necessary, because you have to confirm admin rights for each window individually.

Comment: There is one drawback to this solution: When ConEmu starts with startup.txt script then every time when "Create new console" button is pressed all consoles defined in the startup.txt are created again.  Lines like following one are used in the startup.txt:  `set "PATH=%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & %ProgramFiles%\Git\git-cmd.exe --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:d:C:\Project\Project1 -cur_console:t:project1`

Comment: It can be avoided by selecting "Default task for new console" in one of the Predefined tasks.